# Tweet high quality images

Tags: export, social-media

I'm trying to export images to a twitter account with mathematica and the quality of the images is rather disappointing.

[image]

Here are the others in case you want to see it in the wild: [here](https://twitter.com/tsure)

This is the code I use to export.

```
ServiceExecute[twitter, "ImageTweet", {"Image" -> plot}]
```

Where `plot` is the output of a simple `ListLinePlot` function. Cannot find any documentation about this. I tried making the image larger but that only made for a larger and uglier post. Any help is appreciated.

As per comments, the rasterized image looks like this when exported to my computer:

[image]

but if I tweet the image the result is quite ugly:

[image]

I didn't add a mwe before since you need a tweeter account to try it, but here it is:

```
twitter = ServiceConnect["Twitter"]
plot = Rasterize[
  ParametricPlot[{Sin[t], Cos[t] + Sin[\[Pi] t]}, {t, 1, 10}, 
   Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, Background -> Hue[color], 
   ImageSize -> Large], RasterSize -> 2000, ImageSize -> 800]
ServiceExecute[twitter, "ImageTweet", {"Image" -> plot}]
```

Comment: Why not use `Rasterize[]` first to ensure an image of known resolution is being tweeted?

Comment: In the absence of further information, I don't see how we can judge what makes an image "disappointing," so the advice by @J.M. is the only safe answer. If this doesn't work, you'd have to supply a MWE in *Mathematica* code.

Comment: @Jens I hope now it's clear what I mean by disappointing images. I wonder if this is a tweeter or mathematica issue.

Comment: You should always give `"Image"` as the second argument to `Rasterize` for preserving quality on export, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/94535/280) detailed explanations. But it does not explain the catastrophic loss of the quality in your case; looks like your image is tweeted in a lossy JPEG format.

Comment: Can you show me the actual image and the one that is being uploaded to twitter? Also which version of Mathematica are you using? And what is PacletInformation["ServiceConnection_Twitter"] gives you?

Comment: @dsingh mma 10.3.1 in macosx 10.8.5 the images I'm uploading to twitter are the second and third, first what I see in my computer and then the tweeter version. `PacletInformation["ServiceConnection_Twitter"]` returns `{}`

Comment: @tsuresuregusa I cannot reproduce it. I can see the same image being uploaded to twitter as is the actual image shown on my computer or with Import["imagepath"] in mathematica!

Comment: @dsingh weird. Are you also in mac?

Comment: @tsuresuregusa  yes I checked it on mac 10.11.4